# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose a sequence {$a_n$} converges to a limit $l$ as $n$ tends to infinity. This means, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = l$. From what I understand, this would also mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = l$, because for a convergent sequence consecutive terms should become equal (to a limit) as $n$ tends to infinity (correct me if I'm wrong here).

If that's true, then $\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n} = 1$

Or, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$, for a convergent sequence. But this doesn't seem to be correct. What is that I'm missing here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Please explain.

Comment: You're missing that you can apply arithmetic of limits under certain conditions. For example, $$\lim\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\lim a_n}{\lim b_n}$$ as long as both $\;\lim a_n,\,\,\lim b_n\;$ exist **finitely** and $\;\lim b_n\neq 0\;$ ...! A counter example of what you wrote after "If that's true..." is $\;a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n\;$ .

Comment: So why don't you try a counterexample?

Comment: What about $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n!}$ ? Or $a_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi^n}$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay, so when $l=0$, I cannot take the fraction. But what if $l$ is a non-zero real number? Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$ then?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I checked the link you provided. But that discusses the case when $l =0$. Can you provide a case where $l$ is non-zero and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1$?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser If the limit of $a_n$ exists and is nonzero then the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is one. See DonAntonio's remark.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yeah, I get that. But when I asked specifically the case where $l$ is non-zero, Dietrich Burde said that it is still not equal to $1$. Check the comment above.

Comment: Well I'll let Dietrich Burde clarify that comment.  If $a_n$ is zero for some $n$ then $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is not even a well-defined sequence.  However, it is still sensible to talk about the *limit* of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ when the limit of $a_n$ is nonzero, in which case the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is one.

Comment: That comment seems to be deleted now. So I guess, I understand the picture better now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to some real number $L,$ then its shifted sequence $(a_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ also converges to $L.$ However, if $L=0,$ then you obviously cannot have $\frac{L}{L}=1.$ Hence, the division you performed presupposes $L\neq0.$